# Sql server index usage depending on column value

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-indexes

I have a huge table (it has more than 40 milion records) and an index on one of the column. The column is a reference column - typeId.

I run into an issue that while filtering the data on that column using different column values, the index is sometimes being used and sometimes not.

Eg. simply running:

```
select * from LargeNumberOfItemsTable where typeid=4
```

makes SQL Server use index, but

```
select * from LargeNumberOfItemsTable where typeid=3
```

does not use index.

When the index is not being used, the query takes a long time, but when I force a hint that the index should be used, it takes just seconds to run it.

The strange thing is that statistics have been updated and the index has been rebuilt.

Does anyone have an idea, why such behaviour could occur? I'm looking for some hints where to look for the cause.

Comment: Have you updated statistics?

Comment: Yes, the statistics have been updated.

Comment: include the actual execution plan for both queries, use this link (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and include in the question

Comment: Can you share the execution plans?

Comment: Rebuilding with "MAXDOP 1" option solved the problem

Comment: Now both plans are same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server chooses the plan based on estimated row counts. If the estimated row counts are accurate, the time taken for a full table scan versus a seek and key lookup will depend much on your hardware and available resources.

Make sure indexes were rebuilt with MAXDOP 1. Otherwise, the out-of-order extents will mitigate the benefits of read-ahead scans, causing the plan with the scan to perform more poorly when data are not cached.

Comment: Thanks! That was it :D

Comment: How do you determine when an index would benefit from rebuilding using `MAXDOP 1`

Comment: @Mazhar, a rebuild with MAXDOP 1 is ideal for a workload that does a lot of scans. However, that will increase rebuild time. One could also use reorganize instead of rebuild, which is single threaded and online by nature.